# printing line number in c using getchar and putchar

Tags: c, numbers, counter, getchar, putchar

is there a way to print out the line number in C while only using `putchar` and `getchar` and no arrays?

the output should look like this.
for example input `mink`

```
01: mink
02: jaguar
```

and so on

The line number should go from `01` to `50`.

This is my start approach

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    int counter = 1;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        if (c == '\n') {
            putchar(counter + '0');
            putchar(':');
            putchar(' ');
            ++counter;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the line number is only 2 digits, compute and output these digits and the `:` prefix. To avoid duplicating code for the beginning of the file and to avoid printing a line number for the non-existing line after the end of the file, print the line number before the first character of each line, that is *after* the newline if there is another character. Initializing `lastc` to `'\n'` ensures a line number is printed before the first line of the file, if there is at least one line.

Here is a simple imlementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, lastc = '\n';
    int counter = 1;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (lastc == '\n') {
            putchar('0' + counter / 10 % 10); // tenths digit
            putchar('0' + counter % 10);      // units digit
            putchar(':');
            putchar(' ');
            counter++;
        }
        putchar(c);
        lastc = c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your comment but I am not allowed to use print f

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the fact that you cannot use `printf` to output the line number. If you can assume the line number to be between `1` and `99`, it is rather simple: at the beginning of each line, compute and output the 2 digits and the `: `.

Comment: Thank you very much :) sorry english is not my first language but what exactly do you mean by "at the beginning of each line, compute and output the 2 digits and the : " I have trouble understanding and what does the lastc = c; do?

Comment: I want the program  to print the line numbers from 01 to 99 after that it should print out the output without line numbers what approach should I take?

Comment: Add a test to only output the line number if `counter < 100`

Comment: Thank you sooo much

Comment: sorry one more question I don't really understand the if(lastc=='\n') why lastc and not c? I understand that if I say if(c=='\n') it will print the output before the line number. But how does c=getchar know that last c is my last character?

Comment: so my main question how does getchar know that lastc ist my last character?

Comment: `lastc` is a separate variable to store the previous character read from the file. Maybe I should have named it `prevc`... I initialize it to `'\n'` to ensure that the line number `01` is printed before the first line of output, and I store the value of `c` into it at the end of the loop, so it is always the value of the previous character when I call `getchar` again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do division and mod by 10 to get the 10's digit and the one's digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    int counter=1;
    putchar('0');
    putchar('1');
    putchar(':');
    putchar(' ');
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        putchar(c);
        if ( c == '\n' ) {
            ++counter;
            putchar(counter / 10 + '0');
            putchar(counter % 10 + '0');
            putchar(':');
            putchar(' ');

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer but if the input is for example box then the output looks like this 01: newline

Comment: how can I modify the code that the output looks like this 01: box

Comment: I also want the line numbering to go from 01: to 50: do i need a do while loop for that?

Comment: @momonosuke See my edits. You could do a do-while, but then the also have to do c = getChar() outside of the loop

Comment: I tried putting the c = getchar() outside the main while loop and after the do while loop however I still get an endless loop